# 404 every page on frontend after upgrade 2.4.x

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, 404, magento2.4.5

After Upgrade Magento 2.4.5-p1, I got 404 on every page on the frontend. The CSS and JS URLs are correct.  The admin is working fine.

When I changed the 404 page it changed the 404 page to added page. But after it's shown same page show on every page.

https://prnt.sc/DtBvsqyyHksX

When I disable the store code, pages show, but we need to show the store code in the URL. So anyone can any idea about it?

https://prnt.sc/ADXgNWNfvJMQ

Can anyone Help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please check your store code. I used a store code like below:**

[image]

> **You can check this file code where regular expression which does not allow a (-) Hyphen for store code:**

***vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Validation***

***StoreCodeValidator.php***

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function isValid($value)
{
    $validator = $this->regexValidatorFactory->create(['pattern' => '/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*$/i']);
    $validator->setMessage(
        __(
            'The store code may contain only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore (_),'
            . ' and the first character must be a letter.'
        ),
        \Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH
    );
    $result = $validator->isValid($value);
    $this->_messages = $validator->getMessages();

    return $result;
}
```

> **Create a patch and apply it or overwrite that file in a custom module.**

```
$validator = $this->regexValidatorFactory->create(['pattern' => '/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9_-]*$/i']);
```